# Laravel show method outputs empty object

Tags: laravel

I register a controller in

```
Route::apiResources([
    'products' => 'ProductsController',
]);
```

why would this

```
 public function show(Products $products)
 {
    // return $products;
    return response()->json($products);
 }
```

return

```
[]
```

When I have data in database

Comment: Did you provide an existing `id` of the product? Also, do `dd($products)` before return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating the name of the parameter in the show method to `$product`. Laravel is going to be looking for the singular variation of the resource name when resolving the route model binding for the show method.

```
public function show(Products $product)
{
   return response()->json($product);
}
```

Also as a side note, it is best practice to name your models as a singular name (`Product`) for more best practices you can check out [this repo](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks didn't knew this was that simple. even though it's simple it's deep. change my whole naming convention

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public function show(Product $product)
 {
    $products = $product->all();
    return response()->json($products);
 }
```